# Open link in private tab Safari Swift

Tags: swift, safari

How do I open a link in a Safari private tab programmatically using Swift?

`UIApplication.shared.openURL` doesn't seem to offer this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no such functionality and I couldn't find any private API that takes you to the incognito mode.

The closest thing you could do to achieve a "private" browsing experience is to implement an in app browser using `WKWebView` and set the data store to `nonPersistent`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore/1532934-nonpersistent

There are other thing like disabling request caching but the non-persistent data store should do it.

Comment: Configure the WKWebView to open in incognito mode ie. nonPersistent for certain URLs while for others it will remain in normal mode.